# How to display status message on web page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, bash

I have a bash script that checks for and deploys new .ear files to the JBoss server.I have linked this script to a web page, so that users can deploy their applications by clicking on the link.
I have also been able to set a status message that the application is being deployed, when a user clicks on the link.(Done using Javascript inside the HTML file).However I am not able to set a 'Deployment completed' message when the script completes execution.
Searching on the net was of little help,though I realized that what I wanted could be achieved using AJAX and requesting for the exit code of the script from the server.Being a system admin and having no knowledge of programming, I wish if somebody could help me out.Below is a part of my HTML file, if that would be of any help:

```
</table>
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="/cgi-bin/auto.sh">
<!--<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Deploy">--!>
<input type="submit" value="Deploy" onClick="showStatusMessage();">
<div id="statusMessage" style="display:none;">
<h3>Your application is being deployed.Please wait.</h3>
</div>
</FORM>

<script>
function showStatusMessage()
{
   document.getElementById("statusMessage").style.display = "block";
}

function hideStatusMessage()
{
   document.getElementById("statusMessage").style.display = "none";
}
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: "that the application is being deployed" - which application, how do you deploy your aplication? Do you build it before deployment?

Comment: The last `!` in `<!--<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Deploy">--!>` is wrong (remove it) and might break your HTML code (as you can see with the syntax highlighter).

Comment: @c0mrade 
What the script does is, it checks for any newly added .ear files in a directory (which is where the applications are located after build), and if it finds one,will copy it to the JBoss server's deploy directory and starts Jboss.

@Felix,
Thanks for that ..I have removed it now.

Answer (score 1):

The only way (i know of) to "know" once a server side deployment is complete.  Would be to poll the server (with ajax) to check the status.